# Styling openstreetmap road, zoom etc

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to create an interactive map with the roads etc. styled in the colors I want. Now, I know about Mapbox, but that is not what we want to use, because in the end it is going to cost us a lot of money, due to fees.
I have been searching the internet for alternatives. I have found lots of pieces of a puzzle, but don't know if those pieces fit into the same puzzle. I also found a lot of "old" software which is not maintained anymore. I am confused!
I think I want/need to start off with OpenStreetMap. I am going to download it and put it on our own server.
To be able to do anything with the OSM tiles, I probably need Leaflet.js.
 But then what? What do I need to style the roads and background, etc.? Is that possible in Leaflet.js? Or do I need to download another piece of software? What is still working and currently active?

Important is that I can show main roads at z0.

Summary:
Map tiles : OpenStreetMap
Use in website : Leaflet.js
Styling colors : ???

Answer (score 2):

OSM tiles (as far a Leaftlet.js is concerned) are PNG files. You can't restyle them: they are bitmaps.

You would need to go back to the raw data and generate new tiles based on that.

[OSM provide documentation](https://openmaptiles.org/styles/).

Comment: Aha. So my way of thinking was wrong... I will look into this. Thank you. I hope I am on the right track now.

Comment: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ is a good resource for starting with your own raster tiles. Since rendering your own tiles is a heavy task you might look for other tile servers that fit your needs. https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ has a list of possible tile servers. Remember to respect the specific terms of use for the tile server you choose.